# Jquery, focusing an element once and then scrollTo next & next & next

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm displaying on a page many pictures. I want to create an animation that center in the middle of the screen the picture that the user just `click`. And then, after any `click` event, I want to display the next picture until the user leave this presentation mode. 
Note: I add the jquery scrollTo script to my code.

Here is what I have done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/qnQSP/3/

HTML

```
<div id="galleries">

    <div id="pictures-content" class="1"><img src="http://www.sb-designs.co.uk/ckfinder/userfiles/images/free%20web%20hosting.jpg"></div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="2"><img src="http://www.mastercreations.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/5.jpg"></div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="3"><img src="http://www.sb-designs.co.uk/ckfinder/userfiles/images/free%20web%20hosting.jpg"></div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="4"><img src="http://www.webdesign4essex.co.uk/images/essex_website_design.jpg"></div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="5"><img src="http://www.mastercreations.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/5.jpg"></div>

</div>
```

Jquery

```
        var next;
        var element_already_focus = 0;
        var oldcurrent = "";        

        $("#galleries #pictures-content").unbind("click");
        $("#galleries #pictures-content").bind("click", function(event) {
            // Count the number of pictures
            var max_number_of_pictures= $('#galleries #pictures-content').length;
    //          console.log("max_number_of_pictures: "+max_number_of_pictures); 

            // Get the binding element class number 
                var picture_number = $(this).attr('class');
    //          console.log("picture_number: "+picture_number);

            // Save the element inside the current variable
                current=$(this);


            // Do a loop to go to the top picture when  
            if(picture_number==max_number_of_pictures)
            {
                next = $("#galleries .1");
            } else 
            { 
                next = $(this).next();
            }

            // Do a loop to go to the bottom picture    
            if(picture_number==1){
                previous = $("#galleries ."+max_number_of_pictures);
            } else { previous = $(this).prev();}


    //      console.log("current: "+$(this).attr("class"));
            if(oldcurrent != "")
            {   
                console.log("old: "+oldcurrent.attr("class"));
// Doing some test
                class_test = parseInt(oldcurrent.attr("class"));
                class_test = parseInt(class_test)+parseInt(1);
                console.log("old: "+class_test);
            }

            console.log("previous: "+previous.attr("class"));
            console.log("current: "+current.attr("class"));
            console.log("next: "+next.attr("class"));

    if(oldcurrent == "")
    {
        $("body").scrollTo(current, 800);
        next = 0;
        console.log("What we do:"+next);
    }
    else{
    // If the element that we are binding have the same class as the old binding element (previous)
    // We are redirecting the user to the next picture
            console.log("oldcurrent "+oldcurrent.attr("class"));
            console.log("current: "+current.attr("class"));
            console.log("next: "+next.attr("class"));

    //   if((oldcurrent.attr("class"))==($(this).attr("class"))||(class_test)==(next.attr("class"))) {
       if((oldcurrent.attr("class"))==(current.attr("class"))||(class_test)==(next.attr("class"))) {   
          $("body").scrollTo(next, 800);    
          next = 1;
          console.log("What we do:"+next);
      }else{
          $("body").scrollTo(current, 800);
          next = 0;
          console.log("What we do:"+next);
      }     
    }

      oldcurrent=current;

        });
```

My problem: I have to click two times on a picture to go to the next one. If I removed the condition, I won't be able to focus another picture when I leave the presentation mode.

I think I have to define a state when the user is in the presentation mode (already click on a picture) and remove this state when he is stoping the presentation mode by moving away.

Does someone has any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking just verify if the image is within the rendered view. If it is then you can assume the clicking is to scroll to the next image.

You can use `$(yourImage).position().top` to know where the image starts. and `$(yourImage).height()` to know it's height.

```
var imageTop =  $(yourImage).position().top,
    imageHeight = $(yourImage).height(),
    windowTop = $(yourImage).height(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

if(imageTop>windowTop && top+height < windowTop+windowHeight){
   Scroll to the next one
}
```

Or if you want the image always stuck to the top:

```
if(imageTop==windowTop){
   Scroll to the next one
}
```

+1 for linking a fiddle

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working great, otherwise, I have to define two different states to be able to manage some css modifications. I published another question...
If you can help it will be great =)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501304/jquery-scrollto-onafter-settings-isnt-working-correctly